# NSOperationsQueue: Managing identical requests

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I need to hit the same `endpoint` in the following situations:

1. When a view reappears on the screen `viewWillAppear`.
2. Every 5 seconds during the life-cycle of a view controller (while the view is being presented).
3. After the app returns from `background` to `foreground`.

This creates at least 2, if not 3, `concurrent` requests to the same `endpoint` when my app returns to `foreground`, especially during a slow internet connection.

I know I can limit the number of `concurrent` requests in the `Queue` to 1, but sometimes I do have a need to hit a few different `endpoints` `concurrently` so I am hoping to find an alternative.

I am using `NSURLSession` with `NSOperationsQueue` to make these calls.  Is there a best practice to handle this with `NSOperationsQueue`?

Comment: You can write a traffic controller class to manage the queue. If the URL operation is pending or was completed within the past 5 seconds then ignore new insertion request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to coalesce (combine) `NSOperation` subclasses that are the same task together so removing any redundant network calls. In order to do this each operation needs to have an `identifier` that is unique to the task (not the operation itself) and can be used to determine if that operation is in the queue. Once an operation has been determined as being in the queue, we can then take the new operation's block/closure callback and insert it into the older operations structure so ensuring that when the older operation's task is complete, both callbacks are triggered. This helps to avoid a scenario where you have missing callbacks in your app.

I've written an article that covers this exact topic:

http://williamboles.me/removing-bolierplate-when-coalescing-nsoperations/

Please note, that this only works for operations that are still in the queue, if you want to limit operations based on a time interval then you need to extend your "traffic controller", like "Code Different" commented.